# hyperlink column in datagrid asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, ajax

I have 3 columns in my `DataGrid`: a *Problem id*, *Solution* and *Hyperlink*.

I want that *hyperlink* to redirect to a new window with a parameter *ProblemId*. And also the size of new window should be small.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: So, what problems do you have with doing that? What is your question?

Comment: You want to open popup window by clicking the hyperlink?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">           
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProblemID" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProblemID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SmallWindow.aspx?id={0}"
                    DataTextField="Click here" NavigateUrl="SmallWindow.aspx" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Solution" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use template field and Row Command Method with the use of

give command id as the ProblemId
and Command Name as HyperLink(or the name u want)

and in rowCommand Event

check e.commandName=="HyperLink"

then do what ever u want in java script

```
ressponse.write(window.open('http://www.domain.com','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.aspx) is what you need.

More [Reading](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) is preferred.

Comment: Your second link is dead. Also, just posting links doesn't help future users especially if the links no longer work. You should include some examples or possible solutions.